# VBA excel , Sumif dynamically row

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to sum all the value that i have checked. For

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUMIF(B1:B5,TRUE,A1:A5)"
```

it works fine, however, when:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUMIF(Range(cells(1,2),cells(lastrow,2)),TRUE,Range(cells(1,3),cells(lastrow,3))"
```

i get compile error. Can anyone please help me.

---

```
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("D1").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUMIF(B1:B5,TRUE,A1:A5)"    'Please help me to convert into Range(cells(1,2),cells(lastrow,2)),True,Range(cells(1,3),cells(lastrow,3))
```

Comment: You are having some syntax issues here... do you want the formula to show up in the cell, or do you want the cell to just have the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have bad syntax for your formula.  You are using VBA reference in an excel formula (will breakdown the points):

```
ActiveCell.Formula = _
"=SUMIF( _  'Application
Range(cells(1,2),cells(lastrow,2)) _ 'VBA
,TRUE, _ 'Application
Range(cells(1,3),cells(lastrow,3)) _ 'VBA
" 'Application
```

---

For having the formula show up in the cell, you would display such that:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUMIF(B1:B" & lastrow & ",TRUE,A1:A" & lastrow & ")"
```

If you want VBA to do the work and you want to output just a value:

```
ActiveCell.Value = Application.SUMIF(Range(Cells(1,2),Cells(lastrow,2)),"TRUE",Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(lastrow,1)))
```

---

Related to your code change, you have previously used column 1 (a) as your sum range, though you list column 3 (c) in your code... i used 1 in my code examples, from your working `SUMIF` function.

Comment: Cyril thanks for the speedy helps! i will try it out and update you the result!

Comment: gosh! it works so magically! HAHA really appreciate your helps! thanks alot Cyril